# Create a Global Store using Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to create a global store using only the Vue 3 Composition API.

Until now I have been doing experimentation, and I read a lot how to use the Composition API, but right know I don't know how to use the `provide` and the `inject`.

All I know is that the `provide` will have all the data that will pass to a child component, so I thought that I should import the store into the `main.ts`. And the code looks like this:

This is the store (src/store/index.ts):

```js
import { reactive, readonly } from "vue";

const state = reactive({
  fnacResults: [],
  interResults: [],
});

export default { state: readonly(state) };
```

This is the `main.ts`:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store/index";

createApp({ provide: { store }, }, App)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

And when the parent component has the data, if I use the `inject`, I will be able to have access to all the data inside of the store. But in my case, it doesn't work. I have a feeling that the error starts when I set the `provide` in my `main.ts` file.

Have you tried to create a global store using the Composition API with `provide` and `inject`?

Btw, my component file (`src/views/Home.vue`) looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ store.state.fnacResults }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  inject: ['store']
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Application API

The `createApp`'s first argument should be a component definition (which would be `App` in your case). Instead, you could use the app instance's [`provide()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#provide):

```js
createApp(App).provide('store', store).mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/creating-a-store-with-vue-composition-api-ki6tn?file=/src/main.js)

### Composition API

With the Composition API, you could [use provide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-provide) like this:

```js
// Parent.vue
import { provide } from 'vue'
import store from '@/store'

export default {
  setup() {
    provide('store', store)
    //...
  }
}
```

Then in some descendent component, you'd [inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#using-inject) it with:

```js
// Child.vue
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = inject('store')

    return {
      results: store.state.interResults
    }
  }
}
```

### Import

Alternatively, it might be simpler to just import the store where you need it, and use it directly:

```js
// Child.vue
import store from '@/store'

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      results: store.state.interResults
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to provide the `store` inside the root component `App` and then use it in any child component :

```
export default {
   name:"App",
  provide: { store },

...
```

Hello component :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, i) in fnacResults" :key="i">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["store"],
  computed: {
    fnacResults() {
      return this.store.state.fnacResults;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.store.state);
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-framework-96c0g?file=/src/App.vue)**